# How do I use Ruby to do a certain number of actions per second?

Tags: ruby

I want to test a rate-limiting app with Ruby where I define different behavior based on the number of requests per second.

For example, if I see 300 request per second or more, I want it to respond with a block.

But how would I test this by generating 300 requests per second in Ruby?  I understand there are hard limitations based on CPU for example, but if I kept the number well below that limitation, how would I still send something that both exceeds the threshold and stays below?

Just looping N-times doesn't guarantee me the throughput.

Comment: This isn't a real answer to your question, but the ratelimit gem, https://github.com/ejfinneran/ratelimit or throttle-queue, https://github.com/ryancalhoun/throttle-queue, will be an inspiration. Basically they count the number of requests within some period, acting differently when you exceed limits set.

Comment: We'd like to see your effort/code toward solving this. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write a tutorial without knowing your expertise level, or the code necessary to perform this, both of which are off-topic. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: Understood -- I couldn't find a place to start beyond a loop that just counted the number of events.   I think these answers below have given me a framework to think about this further.

Answer (score 3):

The quick and dirty way is to spin up 300 threads that each do one request per second. The more elegant way is to use something like [Eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) to create requests at the required rate. With the right non-blocking HTTP library it can easily generate that level of activity.

You also might try these tools:

- [`ab`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) the Apache benchmarking tool, common many systems. It's very good at abusing your system.
- [Seige](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege) for load testing.

Comment: Using the preexisting tools designed for this would be better than trying to reinvent that particular wheel.

Comment: @theTinMan That's why I'm suggesting `ab` as a safe default. The only reason you'd write your own is either as an academic exercise or because you're doing something that requires each request to be procedurally generated.

Comment: yes this is helpful to start looking at it -- I don't want to write my own tool, my original effort was to just use a `loop` which didn't address the rate per second.  Given that it was so far off, there was no code I could present.

Comment: is `ab` a ruby tool?

Comment: @Angela `ab` is [Apache Bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) which comes with the Apache `httpd` server package. It's usually really easy to find for any distribution. It's not the most flexible, but it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

How about a minimal homebrew solution:

```
OPS_PER_SECOND = 300
count = 0
duration = 10
start = Time.now

while true
  elapsed = Time.now - start
  break if elapsed >= duration
  delay = (count - (elapsed / OPS_PER_SECOND)) / OPS_PER_SECOND
  sleep(delay) if delay > 0
  do_request
  count += 1
end
```

Comment: This might not be able to produce 300 requests per second of each request takes more than 3.33ms to complete. Given how slow HTTP can be, that's probably the case. Note that your delay code here sleeps a fixed amount of time, not how much time is left from the last iteration.

Comment: @tadman Over a network, sure. If the server is local, that depends on how fast it is. If you don't get the throughput you want, run as many instances as the server has threads/processes. Adjust `OPS_PER_SECOND` as desired.

Comment: Even if by some magic you could do an HTTP request in 3ms locally, your throttling code doesn't take the amount of time necessary to perform the request into account. What this does is throttle to a *maximum* of 300 operations per second, not exactly that many, and will likely be way lower if the operations take non-trivial time.

Comment: yes, this is what I had tried to originally -- some kind of a loop and a sleep in the case of exceeding  the threshold.  I don't have a super high load to test, they are artificial thresholds so could be set low if needed.

Comment: @tadman You have a good point. However, as stated, this is a "minimal" solution which was written in about 1 minute. It doesn't even attempt to be industrial strength. But sometimes coding up a quick-and-dirty solution in a few minutes is all you need, and doing more is just overengineering. Regarding the "magic" of sub-3ms HTTP request times, there are plenty of HTTP servers which easily go faster than that. If we're talking about the typical Rails app, sure, it would take some "magic".